# What does "get commoditized" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link, but I couldn't understand it.

> Don't let yourself **get commoditized**. Build slowly.

<sub>source: [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/ideas-fueled-Netflix-founder-reed-134743231.html)</sub>

Comment: Does [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commoditization) help?  The advice seems to be that they shouldn't ruin the value of their business by simply becoming a [commodity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/commodity).

Comment: Your link is NG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [*commodity*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/commodity) as used here means:

> noun
>   ( Finance : Investment )
>   A commodity is an item that is traded on the market, such as wheat, gold, silver, oil, coffee, or sugar.

In this sense, for example, every barrel of oil is the same, and when buying as a commodity (say 100 barrels), you don't care which ones you get.

In a business context, this means don't be like every other business, but rather differentiate yourself so that your business will stand out and (hopefully) be desirable to customers.